# How to ensure testing execution order with GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, testing, yaml, integration

I have about half a dozen of integration tests (handled with Robot Framework) to run in a GitLab CI pipeline. Once upon a time, we did not care about the execution order of these tests. The corresponding code (extracted from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file) then looked like the following:

```
test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - pip install RobotNapalm
  script:
    - robot -b debug.log -d log/ ./*.robot
```

But now I need to run those tests in a specific order. What GitLab's doc says about the `script` keyword is that it can handle a handful of commands at once, and then it would look like the following:

```
script:
  - robot -b debug.log -d log/ ./some-test.robot
  - robot -b debug.log -d log/ ./here-is-another-one.robot
  - robot -b debug.log -d log/ ./yet-another-test.robot
```

The doc yet does not say whether those `robot` commands would be handled simultaneously or sequentially. Knowing that I can't influence the tests execution order by giving them alphabetically sorted names, how could I ensure that those tests are executed in a particular order?

Comment: What you put in script will be executed sequentially as in bash script.

Comment: @Tensibai Okay, then it'll be mandatory to sort them in alphabetical order I guess. Do you know of a way to give a specific execution order to GitLab CI?

Comment: The order you write them is the order they will be executed.... there's no magic behind